# how to send a email with cron bash?

Tags: linux, bash, email, cron, ubuntu-14.04

Hi so far i could not send a email with cron, let me explain my current problem :

I have the next bash script :

```
# When the script starts send a email notification
echo "Subject: work completed > /tmp/msg
echo "From: admin@automated" >> /tmp/msg
echo >> /tmp/msg
echo "the work has finished" >> /tmp/msg
echo "some variables here ... " >> /tmp/msg
sendmail mypersonalemail@gmail.com < /tmp/msg

## here the script execute some things
## and when finished it send another email to notify this, and this other email has more variables
```

so when i executed the script manually this works, i mean it send the mail to my email account without any issues, so i try to automated this task for send automatically this mail to certain time with cron, i have to comment that cron works fine with other scripts but particularly with this looks like that cron is not able to send the email and i dont know why, I was investigating but apparently this is a specific problem :(.
not necessarily needs to be cron to automated this task, could be some other utility that you know :)

my OS is ubuntu 14.04.03 LTS

Other question here, i would to know why "sendmail" does not works in ubuntu 15.10 or how to configure it

Cheers

Comment: what does your crontab look like?

Comment: i edit crontab with the command "crontab -e" and it looks like : 15 2 * * * <path_to_my_script.sh> , i tried as well setuo MAILTO in cron but It is not what I'm looking for

Comment: are you including the absolute path?

Comment: obviously, i explain that cron works without any issue with other scripts, so this not the problem

Comment: so then obviously I don't need to ask if the file permissions are correctly set

Comment: yes i have the right permissions

Comment: Try at first to use ``mail`` instead of sendmail, then you can use ``-s "subject line"`` and so on. I suggest using ``filename=$(mktemp)`` to avoid race conditions when writing the message file as well. Next you can write ``$(env)`` to a temp file and compare it to ``env`` in your shell.

Comment: Also, `cron` tend to have very limited `PATH` set. Try using absolute paths for commands used in the script (e.g. `sendmail` in your case...) or explicitly set `PATH` variable in the script.

Comment: Wooow thats the solution, i only specific the full path to sendmail and vuala, it works, but i would like to know how to change the path for cron it would be great know thanks